# Android layouts question

Tags: android, android-layout

What am i doing wrong in the following. also following are my questions

1.In one main.xml file can there be two linear layouts or tale layouts

2.Below on click of button1 i set  linearlayout1's visibility to 'Invisible' but it doesn't happen.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);



Button g_gal =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
final LinearLayout tr1 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
final LinearLayout tr2 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
tr2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

final Button g_gal =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
g_gal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {


        try {
                    tr2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tr1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception while displaying gallery: "+ e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
 });
```

main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:text="Browse Gallery" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <requestFocus></requestFocus>
      </EditText>
      <Button android:text="Send SMS to Nav" android:id="@+id/sms" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
      <Button android:text="Back" android:id="@+id/back1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>


   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

A valid XML file can only have one root, so you can't have two linear layouts as root elements. Create another layout that contains those two layouts as children.

Answer (score 0):

main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout0" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:text="Browse Gallery" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <requestFocus></requestFocus>
      </EditText>
      <Button android:text="Send SMS to Nav" android:id="@+id/sms" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
      <Button android:text="Back" android:id="@+id/back1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.add all other layout under the first LinearLayout.Now you are just finishing the LinearLayout after adding a LinearLayout and a Button

2.To hide layout tr1 try to hide the child

```
int count=tr1.getChildCount();
         for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
             tr1.getChildAt(i).setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

**For question 2.** Instead of setting a View to invisible, set the visibility to View.Gone

```
final LinearLayout tr1 =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
tr1.setVisibility(View.Gone)
```

This is better for layout purposes. Refer to the Android [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) doc for more details.